# Android Studio Error (RecyclerView has no LayoutManager) in Kotlin programing language

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

So I Create Recyclerview on android studio use Kotlin programing language, when I run my code I Get Error, I use Android Studio Version 3.6.3 and API Version 30.

this is my MainActivity.kt :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val exampleList = generateDummyList(500)

    recycler_view.adapter = ExampleAdapter(exampleList)
    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)


}

private fun generateDummyList(size: Int): List<ExampleItem> {
    val list = ArrayList<ExampleItem>()

    for (i in 0 until size) {
        val drawable = when (i % 3) {
            0 -> R.drawable.abdulhalim
            1 -> R.drawable.abdulharisnasution
            else -> R.drawable.abdulmuis
        }

        val item = ExampleItem(drawable, "Item $i", "Line 2")

        list += item
    }
    return list
}}
```

this is my ExampleAdapter.kt :

```
lass ExampleAdapter(private val exampleList: List<ExampleItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder>() {


class ExampleViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val imageView: ImageView = itemView.image_view
    val textView1: TextView = itemView.text_view1
    val textView2: TextView = itemView.text_view2
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ExampleViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
        R.layout.example_item,
        parent, false
    )

    return ExampleViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ExampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = exampleList[position]

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.imageResource)
    holder.textView1.text = currentItem.text1
    holder.textView2.text = currentItem.text2
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

}

this is my ExampleItem.kt :

```
data class ExampleItem(val imageResource: Int, val text1: String, val text2: String) {
```

}

This Is my main_activity.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    tools:listitem="@layout/example_item" />
```

this is my example_item.xml :

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="4dp">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abdulhalim" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view"
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_view1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image_view"
        android:text="Line 2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

this is my Error ON Android Studio :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.recyclerviewbeginners/com.example.recyclerviewbeginners.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.recyclerviewbeginners:layout/activity_main: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{233faa8 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.example.recyclerviewbeginners.MainActivity@f0dfa51
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9 in com.example.recyclerviewbeginners:layout/activity_main: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{233faa8 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.example.recyclerviewbeginners.MainActivity@f0dfa51
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RecyclerView has no LayoutManager androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView{233faa8 VFED..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, adapter:null, layout:null, context:com.example.recyclerviewbeginners.MainActivity@f0dfa51
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.generateLayoutParams(RecyclerView.java:4514)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.recyclerviewbeginners.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7995)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7979)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

this is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.recyclerviewbeginners">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

this is my styles.xml :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"` in RecyclerView xml or remove `tools:listitem` attribute

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/example_item" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you tell us what line 14 in MainActivity.onCreate() is?

If it is one of these two lines:

```
    val exampleList = generateDummyList(500)

    recycler_view.adapter = ExampleAdapter(exampleList)
```

Try to change the order so that layout manager is set before setAdapter() is called:

```
    recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycler_view.setHasFixedSize(true)

    val exampleList = generateDummyList(500)

    recycler_view.adapter = ExampleAdapter(exampleList)
```

Answer (score -1):

⛔ Problem:

```
If you want access the LayoutManager attribute from Activity or Fragment.
```

✅ Solution:

```
You can easy and LayoutManager attribute in layout
```

[image]